# Append Structural Element at the end of a tagged PDF ITEXT

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Currently trying working to see which product can meet our requirements
I have recommend ITEXT because I have used it a lot on the past.

I am working with a Tagged "ADA" (not fully ada in any standard) document:

[image]

My document already has tags, and I am adding one line of text to the end of the page, using the method described on Chapter 15.2.2 of IText in action (2010). The tag gets concatenated below `<Part>` and above the first child element. This is not the desire behavior, since the tag is been added after the and is below all other items.

I have tried using

> PDFStamper

and

> PDFWriter

using the DirectContent and nothing seems to work.

```
          PdfStructureElement eTop = new PdfStructureElement(root, new PdfName("Footer"));

        PdfStructureElement e1 = new PdfStructureElement(eTop, PdfName.P);
        pdfPageContents.BeginMarkedContentSequence(e1);

        pdfPageContents.BeginText();

        pdfPageContents.SetFontAndSize(GetDefaultBaseFont(), fontSize);
        pdfPageContents.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);

        var dict = new PdfDictionary();
        dict.Put(PdfName.ACTUALTEXT, new PdfString(text));
        pdfPageContents.BeginMarkedContentSequence(new PdfName("Span"), dict, true);

        pdfPageContents.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, text, X, Y, 0F);

        pdfPageContents.EndMarkedContentSequence();
        pdfPageContents.EndText();
        pdfPageContents.EndMarkedContentSequence();

        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();
```

I am currently not able to contact itext support because until I have no warranty and it  is possible my clients do not want to buy licencing.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Its unclear what you are asking (at least to me it is).

Comment: In a Tagged PDF i am adding one text to the document but the tags needs to be manually added. I need to add the new tag at the bottom of the tagged structure. How ever the ITEXT example add the tag at the TOP.